# How to if statement in python

Tags: python, csv

I currently have this CSV data stored in a csv file:

```
33.23,1376460060.0,01:01:00.000000
33.29,1376460060.25,01:01:00.250000
33.29,1376460060.5,01:01:00.500000
33.29,1376460060.75,01:01:00.750000
33.33,1376460061.0,01:01:01.000000
33.29,1376460061.25,01:01:01.250000
33.33,1376460061.5,01:01:01.500000
33.29,1376460061.75,01:01:01.750000
33.33,1376460062.0,01:01:02.000000
33.33,1376460062.25,01:01:02.250000
33.37,1376460062.5,01:01:02.500000
33.33,1376460062.75,01:01:02.750000
33.33,1376460063.0,01:01:03.000000
33.33,1376460063.25,01:01:03.250000
33.33,1376460063.5,01:01:03.500000
33.37,1376460063.75,01:01:03.750000
```

Can some one help me on creating an "if statement" or "while loop" which will only show me this:

```
33.33,1376460062.0,01:01:02.000000
33.33,1376460062.25,01:01:02.250000
33.37,1376460062.5,01:01:02.500000
33.33,1376460062.75,01:01:02.750000
```

so I may take out the mean the of column 1.

I am reading my file like this:

```
 Input_Tiempo = raw_input("----INPUT TIME: ")

 Full_InTi = Input_Tiempo 

 #This will convert Full_InTi to time in UNIX
 Full_InTiUNIX = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime("14:08:2013:"+Full_InTi, "%d:%m:%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f").timetuple())

 #reads my csv file
 DATOS = np.genfromtxt(csvname+'NEW.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)

 LISTA = []

 for COLUMN in DATOS:
     INTC= eval(COLUMN[1])
     INTF = float(Full_InTiUNIX)

     if INTF <= INTC:
        if INTF <= INTC:
           print "D: "+COLUMN[0]+" TU: "+COLUMN[1] +" H: " + COLUMN[2]
           LISTA.append(COLUMN[2])
```

So far I have not been able, it will only show want I need.

Comment: Your decision criterion isn't clear; "take out the mean the" doesn't makes sense.  Why do you want those four lines, and not the other 12?  Where is your attempt at writing the **if** statement?

Comment: Why is there an `eval` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want only 1376460062.** as your second column as result then can do following:

```
import csv
with open("csvname",'r') as inp:
    row=csv.reader(inp)
    for i in row:
        if '1376460062' in i[1]:
            print(i)
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give us enough information about your original csv (like the header or the condition to get the line)

For the given data, try something like:

```
import csv

with open('your_file.csv', 'r') as my_csv_file:

    csv_data_dict = csv.DictReader(my_csv_file)
    searched_key = 'the_column_name_of_the_second_data_in_your_line'

    for line in csv_data_dict:
        if '1376460062' in line[searched_key]:
            print line
```